# Facebook Registration Box coming out of iframe

Tags: facebook, iframe

My iframe code is set up as such

```
<iframe 
    src="
          https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration
          ?client_id=
          &redirect_uri=
          &fields=
          [
            {'name':'name'},
            {'name':'email'}, 
            {'name':'phone', 'description':'Your Phone Number','type':'text'},
            {'name':'available','description':'When are you available?'}
          ]
        "

    scrolling="auto"
    frameborder="no"
    style="border:none;"
    allowTransparency="true"
    width="100%"
    height="400">
</iframe>
```

And it works great, no problems with functionality. My problem is that the input boxes are coming out the edge of the iframe, which I do not want.

I'm building my site responsively, so the container is resizing and on mobile browsers (portrait view) it looks like this

[image: input breaking out of iframe]

Is there any way to style this plugin so that instead of having it like this
[image]

I could have it

```
Name of Field
[input]
```

etcetc?

Or will it be easier to have an option to just go to a new page/load up a facebook popup with the registration form in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the iFrame method does not offer clean resizing at widths narrower than ~340px, the [XFBML](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.XFBML.parse) integration should better handle narrow widths down to 260px, and will allow the labels and fields to be on separate lines as you described. See the XFBML section of the [Registration Plugin Docs](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/) for more detail.

Sample code is included below, as well as a screenshot of this flow in FF13.

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script src="//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#appId={YOUR_APP_ID}&xfbml=1"></script>
<fb:registration 
  fields="[{'name':'name'},{'name':'email'}, {'name':'phone', 'description':'Your Phone Number','type':'text'},{'name':'available','type':'text','description':'When are you available?'}]" 
  redirect-uri="https://developers.facebook.com/tools/echo/"
  width="260">
</fb:registration>
```

[image: example]

Answer (score 0):

Those fields seem to have a minimum width and size set. 240px for those on the right and 38% for the labels on the left. I tried to hack it but looks like the only way around would be to build the registration form yourself and POST through the authentication mechanism:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/#fb-root